# Load fact table using informatica

Tags: data-warehouse, informatica-powercenter

How can we load fact table in star schema using informatica powercenter ? Can you please provide any example for mappings/tranformations for this.

Answer (score 1):

to load fact table ,if there is star schema dimentions table are independant at that time lookup on every dimention which you have to load, override the query with only active records check the condition with only natural key means your primary key in dimention after that on that basis take the surrogate key which artifically made by us for loading dimention table and also take which field you want to load in to that fact table.

Answer (score 0):

Take the Staging tables as source tables and take the dimensions as lookups then load the data into fact table.
eg. http://www.folkstalk.com/2012/11/how-to-load-rows-into-fact-table-in.html

Answer (score 0):

[image: Example mapping for loading Fact]

I was not able to find one when I was learning, hence adding this screenshot as a reference for new learners.

the mapping basically looks up at each of the dimension tables, and loads the dimension keys into fact as Foriegn keys and rest of the active records should come from SQ, I have used SQL override to perform all the joins and conditions required for loading the fact records.